# Java int is being compared, but is not making correct comparisons

Tags: java

So I created a game that compares two numbers, `humanChose` and `roomChose`. I have an if statement that compares the two numbers and if the numbers do not match, the console prints out "That is wrong!". If the numbers do match it prints "You're right!". Whatever number key you hit `humanChose` becomes. For example, if you hit the 3 key `humanChose` becomes 3. For some odd reason, if I press 3 and `roomChose` is 2 it still says I am correct no matter what. Any way I can change my code so that it compares the numbers right? Thanks in advance.

Checking Class Code:

```
public class SeeIfRight {
public void seeIfRight(){
    Pick p = new Pick();
    GameStateManager gsm = new GameStateManager();
    MapStateChoose msc = new MapStateChoose(gsm);
    if(p.roomChosen == msc.humanChose ){
        System.out.println("You're right!!!");
    }
    if(p.roomChosen != msc.humanChose ){
        System.out.println("You're wrong!!!");
    }
}

}
```

Number Deciding Code:

```
 public class MapStateChoose {
    private void select1() throws InterruptedException {
            humanChose = 1;
            si.seeIfRight();
        }

        public void keyPressed(int k) throws InterruptedException {
            if(k == KeyEvent.VK_1){
                select1();
            }
            if(k == KeyEvent.VK_2){
                select2();
            }
            if(k == KeyEvent.VK_3){
                select3();
            }
            if(k == KeyEvent.VK_4){
                select4();
            }
            if(k == KeyEvent.VK_5){
                select5();
            }
            }



        private void select5() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            humanChose = 5;
            si.seeIfRight();
        }
        private void select4() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            humanChose = 4;
            si.seeIfRight();
        }
        private void select3() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            humanChose = 3;
            si.seeIfRight();
        }
        private void select2() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            humanChose = 2;
            si.seeIfRight();
        }
```

Pick Class:

```
public class Pick {
public int roomChosen;
    public void pickRoom(Random rand){

        int room = rand.nextInt(99);
System.out.println(room);
if(room < 31){
    roomChosen = 1;
    System.out.println("Treasure has been hidden in the Great Hall!");
}
if(room ==31){
    roomChosen = 2;
    System.out.println("Treasure has been hidden in the Library!");
}
    if(room > 31 && room < 46){
        roomChosen = 2;
        System.out.println("Treasure has been hidden in the Library!");
    }
    if(room == 46){
        roomChosen = 3;
        System.out.println("Treasure has been hidden in the Den!");
    }
    if(room > 46 && room < 52){
        roomChosen = 3;
        System.out.println("Treasure has been hidden in the Den!");

    }
    if(room == 52){
        roomChosen = 4;
        System.out.println("Treasure has been hidden in the Dining Hall!");
    }
    if(room > 52 && room < 80){
        roomChosen = 4;
        System.out.println("Treasure has been hidden in the Dining Hall!");
    }
    if(room> 79){
        roomChosen = 5;
        System.out.println("Treasure has been hidden in the Front Hall!");
    }

    }






}
```

Comment: Do you get the "you found treasure" message multiple times for different rooms?

Comment: Yes. The "you found treasure comes up for no matter what room I click."

Comment: It's because you're not using if else. Multiple conditions are returning true.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not calling the PickRoom() method using p object, so that the roomChoosen variable gets some value and can be compared.